# Why is variable name of array declared on stack not a pointer C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

If I declare two arrays, one on the stack and one on the heap, I get different behavior when printing the variable name (in gdb if that matters).

```
int array_on_stack[5];

int * array_on_heap = new int[5];
```

Now in gdb I step through each line of code and then print the variable name, expecting to get the memory address for each.

```
print array_on_stack

print array_on_heap
```

But for `array_on_stack` it prints the contents of the array and not the memory address.  In order to get the memory address I need the command `print &array_on_stack`.  This suggests that `array_on_stack` is not a pointer.  Can some explain the difference between these two declarations in terms of how to access their memory address and why this is the case?

Comment: That's because they're not the same, one's a pointer, and ones an array; they're different things.

Comment: *This suggests that array_on_stack is not a pointer* You are correct.  Arrays are not pointers.  pointers are pointers and arrays are arrays.  just like `int`s are not `double`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `array_on_heap` is not an array: it's a pointer (to the first item of a dynamically allocated array).

Arrays are arrays, pointers are pointers.

Hence you will get similar results in gdb for

```
int* array_with_automatic_storage = &array_on_stack[0];
```

Comment: I thought in C++ arrays degrade to pointers so that the variable name was simply a pointer pointing to the first object.  That is why we can declare arrays in both ways.

Comment: @xjtc55: Yes, in the declaration above you can replace `&array_on_stack[0]` with just `array_on_stack`, taking advantage of implicit conversion to pointer, an array expression /decay/ to pointer type. But array expressions don't always decay and arrays are not pointers. In particular you can't assign a pointer to an array variable.

Comment: There is a [C++ array FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) question here on SO, mostly written by Fred Overflow and me. You could do worse than reading it. There is also some [C++ array documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays#t=201610191331403254374) here on SO, created and mostly written by me. I mention the authors up front as common disclosure.